# Creating advanced HL7 message with Hapi Fhir

Tags: java, hl7, hapi, hapi-fhir

I am trying to teach myself to use the Hapi Fhir api and I'm starting by creating an HL7 message from Java. I have been able to do so by looking at [this example](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/xref/ca/uhn/hl7v2/examples/CreateAMessage.html) from the official documentation page. However, now I would like to add some more information to my message by adding the NK1, PV1 and AL1 segments to the message (now it only contains the MSH and PID). I couldn't find any more complete examples, even looking into github code. How can I tackle this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HAPI help appropriate to your HL7v2 message version. For example - http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/v25/apidocs/index.html

Thus:

```
public PV1 getPV1()
```

Returns PV1 (Patient Visit) - creates it if necessary